# Post-404 No found error on register/login page using Node.Js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, backend

I am making a Register and Login page. I can't get an answer from the page.I couldn't find the error even though I examined the POST method examples.

This is the whole code

```
import { useState } from 'react'


function App() {


    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

    async function registerUser(event) {
        event.preventDefault()

        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/register', {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })

        const data = await response.json()

        if (data.status === 'ok') {
            history.push('/login')
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form onSubmit={registerUser}>
                <input
                    value={name}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Name"
                />
                <br />
                <input
                    value={email}
                    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Email"
                />
                <br />
                <input
                    value={password}
                    onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                />
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

The part of the site that gives an error

```
const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/register', {
            method:"POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name,
                email,
                password,
            }),
        })
 Register.js:14          POST http://localhost:3000/api/register 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the part where I use this function. I don't think a possible bug here will affect the POST method, but I'm sharing it anyway.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const User = require("./models/user.model")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test-db")

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.post("/api/register",async(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    try {
         await User.create({
            name:req.body.name,
            email:req.body.email,
            password:rawListeners.body.password
        })
        res.json({status:"ok"})
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({status:"error",error:"Duplicate email"})
    }
})
app.post("/api/login",async(req,res)=>{
        const user= await User.findOne({
            email:req.body.email,
            password:req.body.password
        })

        if(user){
            return res.json({status:"ok", user:true})
        }else{
            return res.json({status:"error",user:false})
        }
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log("Server started")
})
```

and

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes,Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Register from './pages/Register'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
            </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Examined the post method, I guess there is a mistake. There is no problem with the port in the Fetch section.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

So I took a look at your code, and I think the problem might be here:

```
...
return (
    <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
)
....
```

The path for the registration page is `/register`, yet you're using `/api/register` elsewhere. This may give you the error, as it tries sending a POST request to a non-existent endpoint.